# Alternate solution for the query - Used INTERSECT function in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on the query. I have two tables one is detail table where not grouping happen and its like including all the values and other table is line table which has important column grouped together from detail table.

I want to show all the column from line table and some column from detail table.

I am using below query to fetch my records

```
SELECT ab.*, 
       cd.phone_number, 
       cd.id 
FROM   xxx_line ab, 
       xxx_detail cd 
WHERE  cd.reference_number = ab.reference_number 
       AND cd.org_id = ab.org_id 
       AND cd.request_id = ab.request_id 
       AND ab.request_id = 13414224 

INTERSECT

SELECT ab.*, 
       cd.phone_number, 
       cd.id 
FROM   xxx_line ab, 
       xxx_detail cd 
WHERE  cd.reference_number = ab.reference_number 
       AND cd.org_id = ab.org_id 
       AND cd.request_id = ab.request_id 
       AND ab.request_id = 13414224
```

The query is working fine...

But I want to know is there any other way for I can achieve the same result by not even using Intersect.

I purpose is to find out all possible way to get the same output.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: you have two *identical* sub-queries so the INTERSECT won't affect the outcome.  If you want us to give you advice you need to make us understand what you're trying to achieve.  Currently you are failing in this.  Please post some sample data and give us an indication of your desired output.  Help us to help you.

Comment: @APC The implicit distinctness of the INTERSECT operator does make a difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`INTERSECT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries004.htm#SQLRF52346) operator returns the *unique* set of rows returned by each query.  The code can be re-written with a `DISTINCT` operator to make the meaning clearer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       xxx_line.*, 
       xxx_detail.phone_number, 
       xxx_detail.id 
  FROM xxx_line
  JOIN xxx_detail
    ON xxx_line.reference_number = xxx_detail.reference_number
   AND xxx_line.org_id = xxx_detail.org_id
   AND xxx_line.request_id = xxx_detail.request_id
 WHERE xxx_line.request_id = 13414224
```

I also replaced the old-fashioned join syntax with the newer ANSI join syntax (which makes relationships clearer by forcing the join tables and conditions to be listed close to each other) and removed the meaningless table aliases (because code complexity is more directly related to the number of variables than the number of characters).